# Azure PowerShell script - Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Name'

Tags: powershell, azure, build, asp.net-core, azure-devops

I have created a CI Build on Visual Studio Team Services to build my ASPNET 5 website.

I followed the steps in [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/azure/deploy-aspnet5).

I have the first PowerShell script pulling down DNX and the Project is building successfully through the Build step.

However, the Azure PowerShell script step is failing.

To debug it, I created a simple PSPing.ps1 script contains only the following:

`Write-Host "Hello World"`

The structure of the build process is as follows:

[image]

When I run the process, I receive the following error:

`ScriptPath= C:\a\1\s\scripts\PingAuth.ps1
scriptCommand= & "C:\a\1\s\scripts\PingAuth.ps1" 
Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Name'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
Cannot index into a null array.
Deploy Url: 
Website Name:`

I don't understand this error and I don't understand where **Deploy Url** and **Website Name** come from?

Comment: Downvote, please post the code that is causing the problems not a link.  It's also helpful to include what you've tried to resolve the problem.

Comment: I've included an image of the build steps.  I did explain what I did to try and solve the issue - I created a simple PowerShell script and added it as the first step.

Answer (score 0):

According to the link, the `PublishAspNet5Website.ps1` script is looking for two parameters.  [See this page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743.aspx) for more about advanced parameters.

The first line of that script is `param($websiteName, $packOutput)` which means the script has to be executed as such `PublishAspNet5Website.ps1 -websiteName {WebSite}` `-packOutput $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\{yourProjectName}\artifacts\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\Publish`

These parameters are seen in step 12.

12.
In the Script Arguments input add the following parameters. -websiteName {yourWebsiteName} -packOutput $(Build.SourcesDirectory){yourProjectName}\artifacts\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\Publish

Comment: I removed the param(...) from the initial Azure PowerShell step and from the .ps1 script that I pointed that step at.  I did that to try and simplify things while debugging.

As you can see, there is a second PowerShell step later in the process which is the same as the one in the article.